# How can I get mouse-track-delete-and-insert in emacs?

Tags: emacs

One of my favourite xemacs features is the ability to zap chunks of text from one place to another with a mere gesture: mouse-track-delete-and-insert. Is it possible to do the same in emacs?

This is the help entry:

> C-Sh-button1 runs `mouse-track-delete-and-insert'
>
> `mouse-track-delete-and-insert' is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function   -- loaded from
>   "c:\XEmacsBuild\xemacs-21.4.22\lisp\mouse.elc"
>   (mouse-track-delete-and-insert EVENT)
>
> Documentation: Make a selection with the mouse and insert it at point.
>   This is exactly the same as the `mouse-track' command on button1,
>   except that point is not moved; the selected text is immediately
>   inserted after being selected; and the text of the selection is
>   deleted.

Comment: The function `mouse-track-delete-and-insert` is not coming up in a current version of Emacs Trunk built a couple of weeks ago, and I loaded the mouse library before trying to locate said function.  Maybe it goes by a different name now, or it is in another library that needs to be loaded first?  Perhaps it would just be as simple as copying the function over to your `.emacs` file along with whatever dependencies it needs, and then map it to whatever mouse gesture you want.

Comment: @lawlist, note that the help entry mentioned in this question is from *XEmacs*, not GNU Emacs.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the command works?

Comment: It's used to copy or move text from one place to another. Set point to the destination, then ctrl-select some text (e.g. ctrl-double-click). I use it a lot, for example building some SQL on the command line by grabbing bits of SQL from other buffers and IDs from log files.

Comment: Holding control and selecting text copies text. ctrl-shift-select moves it which is also really useful. The closest I've found in gnu emacs so far is to select, copy, move the point to the destination and paste.